# In exwm (Emacs X Window Manager) how can I assign apps to particular workspaces?

Tags: exwm

For example, no matter in which workspace I start Firefox, I want it to launch in workspace 2. In `i3wm` I can do this with `assign [class="(?i)firefox"] $workspace2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exwm-manage-finish-hook` to perform functions when a window has loaded. Combine that with `exwm-class-name` and `exwm-workspace-move-window` and you could do something like this:

```
(require 'subr-x)  ;; Because of when-let

(defvar exwm-workspace-window-assignments
  '(("Firefox" . 2)
    ("Thunderbird" . 3))
  "An alist of window classes and which workspace to put them on.")

(add-hook 'exwm-manage-finish-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when-let ((target (cdr (assoc exwm-class-name exwm-workspace-window-assignments))))
              (exwm-workspace-move-window target))))
```

So now a window named Firefox would end up on workspace 2, while Thunderbird would end up on workspace 3. You could add more entries to `exwm-workspace-window-assignments` if you want. Keep in mind that the workspace need to exist before trying to move a window to it.

The code snippet above needs Emacs 25, because of `when-let`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set this using `EXWM` settings (it is possible that this option did not exist at the time the question was first answered):

```
(setq exwm-manage-configurations
   '((string= exwm-instance-name "firefox")
      workspace 2))
```

You can also set this variable with `M-x customize-variable` Ret `exwm-manage-configurations`.